# Checking how many colors my terminal emulator supports

Tags: terminal-emulator

Is there a reliable way to check how many colors my terminal emulator supports?

If `echo $TERM` prints `xterm`, does that **unequivocally** tell me how many colors my terminal emulator supports? How could I check this information reliably?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/how-to-check-if-bash-can-print-colors

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The value of `$TERM` does not give much information about the number of supported colors. Many terminals advertise themselves as `xterm`, and might support any number of colors (2, 8, 16, 88 and 256 are common values).

You can query the value of each color with the `OSC 4 ; c ; ? BEL` [control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.txt). If the color number `c` is supported, and if the terminal understands this control sequence, the terminal will answer back with the value of the color. If the color number is not supported or if the terminal doesn't understand this control sequence, the terminal answers nothing. Here's a bash/zsh snippet to query whether color 42 is supported (redirect to/from the terminal if necessary):

```
printf '\e]4;%d;?\a' 42
if read -d $'\a' -s -t 1; then … # color 42 is supported
```

Among popular terminals, xterm and terminals based on the VTE library (Gnome-terminal, Terminator, Xfce4-terminal, …) support this control sequence; rxvt, konsole, screen and tmux don't.

I don't know of a more direct way.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. This looks great. May I ask what `read -d $'\a' -s -t 1` does?

Comment: @intrpc Read input until the first `\a` (bell character), without echoing input, with a timeout of 1 second.

Comment: The result on my terminal (color 42 is supported) is inconsistent with `tput colors`, which returned `8`. What gives?

Comment: @l0b0 `tput colors` queries the terminfo database. Chances are that you have `TERM=xterm`. Xterm can support at least 2, 8, 16, 88 or 256 colors depending on the version and on compile- and run-time options, but the terminfo database can only store one value. You can set e.g. `TERM=xterm+256color`, but then you'll be annoyed when you log in to a machine that doesn't have this entry in its termcap/terminfo database.

Comment: @Gilles: Is it possible to `read` this non-interactively from the terminal? I've tried a `printf | while read`, but it just gets the characters from `printf`, not what will actually be printed by the terminal.

Comment: @l0b0 Your pipe obviously has nothing to do with the terminal. You need to print to the terminal (`printf … >/dev/tty`) and then read from the terminal (`read … </dev/tty`). Xterm responds to the `OSC 4; …; ? BEL` sequence by injecting keystrokes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Here's a [script to determine how many colors your XTerm *actually* supports](https://github.com/l0b0/xterm-color-count).

Comment: @l0b0: In Konsole it shows 0 whereas *actually* it supports 256 colors...

Comment: @jamadagni Unfortunately Konsole doesn't support the control sequence we use. Thanks, I added a mention of that in my answer. l0b0: it might be useful to add a sanity check in your script: if the terminal doesn't even seem to support color number 1, the information is clearly not reliable.

Comment: @Gilles: Is there then any way to find out the correct number of colors on Konsole/Yakuake? Or should I just assume that since I'm running it under a full-color X session all 256 will be available? Is then there any way to find that the current terminal is controlled by Konsole/Yakuake?

Comment: @jamadagni Thanks - I've added a [bug report](https://github.com/l0b0/xterm-color-count/issues/1) and I'd be happy to merge a pull request.

Comment: @l0b0: Thanks for taking feedback into account. I have no pull request to make simply because I don't know how to fix it. I'm hoping Gilles or another such expert can chime in. From [this page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/256_Color_Terminals) it would seem that the only reliable way is to get terminal emulators to set the `TERM` variable correctly with a `-256color` suffix... :-(

Answer (score 22):

You can use

```
$ tput colors
```

On my debian install tput is part of the `ncurses-bin` package which is installed by default.

Comment: That will only inform how many colors your terminal is *reporting* to the environment via `TERM`, not how many colors it can actually *support* given an appropriate `TERM`

Answer (score 13):

There is a perl script, **[256colors2.pl](https://code.google.com/p/joeldotfiles/source/browse/trunk/256colors2.pl)**, that will display all the colours on your terminal.

Comment: With Google Code offline, this seems an alternative: https://gist.github.com/hSATAC/1095100

Comment: Or more at [*Print a 256-color test pattern in the terminal* - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821157/print-a-256-color-test-pattern-in-the-terminal).