# tmux, Vim and Solarized

Tags: vim, tmux, colors

## Premises

Browsing around *tmux*, *Vim* and *Solarized* I can find lots of complains about 256 colours and "user experience". Well, I'm having the opposite "problem", i.e. *Vim* works well with a full *Solarized* theme **only** in *tmux*.

## Background

I've been tweaking and tuning around for a bit now with my *Ubuntu* terminal's and *Guake*'s colour scheme and I almost got to the perfection which is reached when I'm using *tmux*, which in turn means always. I'm trying now to understand **why** this is happening.

Here below there are two Terminals, the one on the left is running only *Vim* (showing the current `.vimrc`) whereas the other is running *Vim* inside a *tmux* session. As you can clearly see, only in the *tmux* session the fonts are bold, which I guess is *correct* (or not?).

[image]

## Question

Why does *tmux* allow for bold font whereas the terminal, where *tmux* is running, does not? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $TERM` in and out of `tmux`?

Comment: *tmux* says `screen` whereas *terminal* says `xterm` :)

Comment: @jasonwryan read the OP's other question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118806/22222) and Gilles's answer to a similar one [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23789/22222). Apparently `$TERM` is not that relevant.

Comment: @terdon it is material in this case: tmux requires that the term is set to screen (or a variant) and xterm is, by default, an 8 colour term. That's why the OP is seeing the difference.

Comment: Put `xterm*termName: xterm-256color` in your `~/.Xresources` and see if that makes a difference...

Comment: I'm not that sure I understood exactly what you meant. Anyway, I created a new `~/.Xresources` and entered the line `xterm*termName: xterm-256color`, saved and opened a new *terminal*. Nothing changed. (But I've never sourced the new `~/.Xresources`.) Shall I do something more?

Comment: `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` and then open a new terminal and check the value of $TERM...

Comment: **@illuminÉ**, what you see is the **current** `~/.vimrc` configuration file, not the one I use everyday. My question is about **understanding** why the same (strictly necessary) configuration has two different outputs when you run *Vim* in *Terminal* and in *tmux*.

Comment: @Atcold I hear you. I can't reproduce that with lxterminal and t_Co=256. I have the exact same output. It's clear in the first image the secondary attributes i.e. bold etc. are not rendered like you noted. I'll think about it...

Comment: @jasonwryan, I did as you said and `echo $TERM` still answers `xterm`. Furthermore, nothing changed. *Vim* shows me (correct?) bold font only within *tmux*. Anything else that I could try in order to understand what's going on? [Question: how do I revert the `xrdb` merging? Rebooting would do the job?]

Comment: Just run `xrdb` again after making changes to your `~/.Xresources` and it will update the server with your new config. It looks like you don't have a 256 colour terminfo for your `xterm`.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I am a bit lost. Actually, I'm not following what you are trying to test. It would be nice if you could add some explanations or references. On the other side, I've answered my question myself. Now (see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119988/38879)) I have a following up question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Short answer

It's a bug.

## Full answer

It looks like the "correct" visualisation is the one on the left, where the **bold font** are **not** rendered. For what I could understand ([here](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized#bold-settings) is the reference) the bold attribute was used, originally, to set the *highlighted* version of the 8 base colours.

> *Historically, there has been a one-to-one correspondence between the bolded versions of the 8 default ANSI colors and the bright versions of the 8 default colors. Back in the day, when a color program demanded the display of bold text, it was probably just easier for terminal emulators to display a brighter version of whatever color the text was (and expect the user to interpret that as bold) than to display a typeface with a bold weight.*

Basically, what is happening here is that, in order to use the full *Solarized* palette, with the *orange*, *purple* and all the levels of *grey*, the colours are called with the *bold attribute*, which in turn refers to the *alternative* 8 colours of the ANSI palette.

*Terminal* understands this correctly, and shows the *orange* and the *comment grey* in *normal* typesetting, whereas *tmux* adds an unnecessary *bold* font to them. In conclusion, the left side is correct whereas the right one is not.

## Question 2

Is there a way to *disable* the bold rendering of *tmux*?
I still have to do some research about it, and I will update this answer as soon as I find something.

## Answer 2

And here we have the solution! :)

In order to have *tmux* behave correctly we have to call it telling him that we are in a 256 colours enabled environment.

```
TERM=xterm-256color /usr/bin/tmux
```

For convenience we could `alias` this (i.e. you add `alias tmux="<the line above>"` to your `~/.bashrc`).

[image: tmux interprets correctly the non-bold "bold-alternative" colours]

Calling `tmux` as `tmux -2`, for forcing *tmux* to run with 256 colours support (instead of redefining the `TERM` environmental variable) will not allow for correct interpretation of the "bold-alternative" 8 colours (i.e. the brighter variant will also result having a bold typesetting). Therefore, I highly recommend to use the solution here above for having **both** correct 256 colours interpretation **and** non-bold "bold-alternative" colours.

Comment: much love man!!