# Vim not loading color scheme file at all

Tags: centos, vim, colors

I have exactly same two CentOS 6 boxes. Trying to install `vim` and enable color scheme file.

Same thing, same `vim` versions used but the color scheme works in one machine and not in other.

Here are info:

```
# vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jul 24 2015 02:23:23)
...... +syntax

# cat ~/.vimrc
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
color termschool

# ll ~/.vim/colors/
termschool.vim
```

Everything are "exactly" same on both Server. But the `color scheme` file is working on one but not on another one.

Here is what's happening:

- When i edit a file using `vim`, it always falls into `default` scheme. (So it shows default colors)
- When i remove the color scheme file `~/.vim/colors/termschools.vim`, then the `vim` shows **error message**. (So, that means `vim` still looks for the color scheme file, which is correct manner)
- But when i put the file back again, nothing happens but the `default` color are loaded again.

I'm very confused now. Any advice please?

Comment: Do you use the same terminal emulator on both hosts ? It might be that the number of colors supported by the emulators are different. Vim defaults to the default color scheme if the theme colors are not supported. See the [caveats section in the readme of the github repositoty of the theme](https://github.com/marcopaganini/termschool-vim-theme#caveats)

Comment: I'm using the Same MacBook Terminal.

Comment: If you `echo $TERM` on both the values are identical ? Anyway [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23763/checking-how-many-colors-my-terminal-emulator-supports) can help you check the number of colors

Comment: Are the termschool.vim files also identical?