# Color script output only when invoked from interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, colors

I made a bash script producing colored output. The colors are fine when the script is called from an interactive shell. However, if the output is processed in another script, or passed through a pipe, it should not be colored (I think).

How is this handled usually? Should I provide an option to turn on/off the colored output, or is there a way to detect this automatically in the script? Preferably it works automatically and I only need a minimum of code to output colored / non-colored, depending on the script invocation...

One problem with automatic detection seems to be that a script always runs non-interactive, so I would have to know the interactive status of the parent shell instead.

Comment: I vote for option.

Comment: Taking a look at various unix commands such as `ls` and `grep` they all offer a `--color` switch of varying sorts, so I'd say add a switch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if bash can print colors](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/how-to-check-if-bash-can-print-colors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is common for unix application that do support colour output (such as `grep` and `ls`) to have a command line option as well as possibly automatic detection.

looking at `man ls` we see

```
--color[=WHEN]
              colorize the output.  WHEN defaults to `always' or can be `never' or `auto'.  More info below
```

So by default ls will always use colour, notice the `auto` option.

`man grep` shows similar

```
 --color[=WHEN], --colour[=WHEN]
              <snipped> WHEN is never, always, or auto.
```

If the `auto` option is enabled (which for your application could be the default) then something like the following answer (suggested by Gilles) may be what you are looking for https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10065/4635

That is if your output is a terminal and supports colour, and the user hasn't disabled it you should use color. Of course the user using `always` or `never` skips this check.

I find it useful if programs have a `--color=always` even if they support automatic detection, as this means that I can force colour usage 'when I know better' (say my destination isn't a terminal but I know it supports colour').
On some systems I have an alias for `ls` to `ls --color=always`.

Comment: Sounds good. Also, the question suggested by Gilles does not really apply, but Mikel's answer to the question does. So all I needed is `if [ -t 1 ]` to check whether the output is printed directly, or being post-processed. I'll add that `--color` option as you suggested.

Comment: @deepc I was actually referring to Mikel's answer, sorry for not specifying. I have corrected my answer to make it explicit. Cheers.