# Where does the TERM environment variable default get set?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, environment-variables, colors

When I open a terminal window with the GNOME Terminal emulator in the desktop GUI the shell TERM environment variable defaults to the value `xterm`.

If I use <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a console TTY window and `echo $TERM` the value is set to `linux`.

My motivation for asking is that inside my `~/.bashrc` file a variable is used to determine if a color shell is provided or just good old fashioned monochrome.

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

In both the console shell and the Gnome Terminal emulator shell if I type

```
export TERM=xterm-color
source /.bashrc
```

both shells change to color mode (something I'd like to have happen always in both).

Where do the default `TERM` values get set please and where is the best place to change their defaults, if at all possible?  There appears to be nothing in the terminal emulator GUI to select or set the default TERM value.

I did consider just adding the line `export TERM=xterm-color` to the top of my `~/.bashrc` file but my gut instinct tells this is not the best solution and my Google searches haven't yet led me to a good answer.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop Edition (Debian Based).

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/how-to-check-if-bash-can-print-colors

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## In lots of places, depending

On virtual terminals and real terminals, the `TERM` environment variable is set by the program that chains to `login`, and is inherited all of the way along to the interactive shell that executes once one has logged on.  Where, precisely, this happens varies from system to system, and according to the kind of terminal.

### real terminals

Real, serial, terminals can vary in type, according to what's at the other end of the wire.  So conventionally the `getty` program is invoked with an argument that specifies the terminal type, or is passed the `TERM` program from a service manager's service configuration data.

- On van Smoorenburg `init` systems, one can see this in `/etc/inittab` entries, which will read something along the lines of

  ```
  S0:3:respawn:/sbin/agetty ttyS0 9600 vt100-nav
  ```

  The last argument to `agetty` in that line, `vt100-nav`, is the terminal type set for `/dev/ttyS0`.  So `/etc/inittab` is where to change the terminal type for real terminals on such systems.
- On systemd systems, one used to be able to see this in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` unit file (`/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` on un-merged systems), which used to read

  ```
  Environment=TERM=vt100
  ```

  setting the `TERM` variable in the environment passed to `agetty`.
- On the BSDs, `init` takes the terminal type from the third field of each terminal's entry in the `/etc/ttys` database, and sets `TERM` from that in the environment that it executes `getty` with.  So `/etc/ttys` is where one changes the terminal type for real terminals on the BSDs.

### systemd's variability

The `serial-getty@.service` service unit file, or drop-in files that apply thereto, is where to change the terminal type for real terminals on systemd systems.  Note that such a change applies to *all* terminal login services that employ this service unit template.  (To change it for only individual terminals, one has to manually instantiate the template, or add drop-ins that only apply to instantiations.)

systemd has had at least four mechanisms during its lifetime for picking up the value of the `TERM` environment variable.  At the time of first writing this answer, as can be seen, there was an `Environment=TERM=something` line in the template service unit files.  At other times, the types `linux` and `vt102` were hard-wired into the `getty` and `serial-getty` service unit files respectively.  More recently, the environment variable has been inherited from process #1, which has set it in various ways.

As of 2020, the way that systemd decides what terminal type to specify in a service's `TERM` environment variable is quite complex, and not documented at all.  The way to change it remains a drop-in configuration file with `Environment=TERM=something`.  But *where the default value originates from* is quite variable.  Subject to some fairly complex to explain rules that involve the `TTYPath=` settings of individual service units, [it can be one of three values](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/693040bde5162c8af3d0f063414288eba5255b3c/src/core/execute.c#L1792): a hardwired `linux`, a hardwired `vt220` (no longer `vt102`), or the value of the `TERM` environment variable that process #1 inherited, usually from the kernel/bootstrap loader.

(Ironically, the `getttyent()` mechanism still exists in the GNU C library, and systemd could have re-used the `/etc/ttys` mechanism.)

### kernel virtual terminals

Kernel virtual terminals, as you have noted, have a fixed type.  Unlike NetBSD, which can vary the kernel virtual terminal type on the fly, Linux and the other BSDs have a single fixed terminal type implemented in the kernel's built-in terminal emulation program.  On Linux, that type matches `linux` from the terminfo database.  (FreeBSD's kernel terminal emulation since version 9 has been `teken`.  Prior to version 9 it was `cons25`  OpenBSD's is `pccon`.)

- On systems using `mingetty` or `vc-get-tty` (from the nosh package) the program "knows" that it can only be talking to a virtual terminal, and they hardwire the "known" virtual terminal types appropriate to the operating system that the program was compiled for.
- On systemd systems, one used to be able to see this in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` unit file (`/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` on un-merged systems), which read

  ```
  Environment=TERM=linux
  ```

  setting the `TERM` variable in the environment passed to `agetty`.

For kernel virtual terminals, one *does not* change the terminal type.  The terminal emulator program in the kernel doesn't change, after all.  It is *incorrect* to change the type.  In particular, this will screw up cursor/editing key CSI sequence recognition.  The `linux` CSI sequences sent by the Linux kernel terminal emulator are different to the `xterm` or `vt100` CSI sequences sent by GUI terminal emulator programs in DEC VT mode.  (In fact, they are highly idiosyncratic and non-standard, and different both to all real terminals that I know of, and to pretty much all other software terminal emulators apart from the one built into Linux.)

### GUI terminal emulators

Your GUI terminal emulator is one of many programs, from the SSH dæmon to `screen`, that uses pseudo-terminals.  What the terminal type is depends from what terminal emulator program is running on the master side of the pseudo-terminal, and how it is configured.  Most GUI terminal emulators will start the program on the slave side with a `TERM` variable whose value matches their terminal emulation on the master side.  Programs like the SSH server will attempt to "pass through" the terminal type that is on the client end of the connection.  Usually there is some menu or configuration option to choose amongst terminal emulations.

## The gripping hand

The right way to detect colour capability is *not* to hardwire a list of terminal types in your script.  There are an awful lot of terminal types that support colour.

The right way is to look at what termcap/terminfo says about your terminal type.

```
colour=0
if tput Co > /dev/null 2>&1
then
test "`tput Co`" -gt 2 && colour=1
elif tput colors > /dev/null 2>&1
then
test "`tput colors`" -gt 2 && colour=1
fi
```

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`TERM`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/TERM.html). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.

Comment: The following exists in the default .bashrc in Debian jessie: `[ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && /usr/bin/tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null && color_prompt=yes`.  (ncurses 5.9)

Comment: Also `tput Co` returns "unknown terminfo capability" in Jessie and Xenial. `tput colors` and `tput setaf 1` both seem to work although I admit I do not understand *why*.

Comment: The clue is that I mentioned both terminfo and termcap.  (-:

Comment: One can still override the setting in `/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` by 
manually adding the `Environment=TERM=vt100` line to the start of the `[Service]` section. Tested on a Debian 12.5.

Answer (score 7):

Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/614714/398785 for my detailed answer on why I think `TERM=xterm-color` is the wrong approach and Ubuntu's `.bashrc` is obsolete. I recommend that you go with `TERM=xterm-256color` (which is the default since gnome-terminal 3.16, but also safe to use with older gnome-terminals), and adjust your `.bashrc` accordingly.

Comment: +1 for your link. Minor suggestion; the following sentence might be confusing (I first got an impression that you were saying that using `.bashrc` is obsolete).

"Ubuntu's .bashrc is obsolete."

Comment: @IsaacS Do you have any suggestion how to improve it? E.g. would replacing "obsolete" with "outdated" help?

Comment: It appears that `xterm-256color` causes `htop` to mess up its layout [like this](https://superuser.com/q/1251360/113004) in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @OrangeDog In which terminal emulator? This question here and thus my response focuses on GNOME Terminal, whereas the page you linked shows Konsole. The bug looks like the terminal emulator doesn't yet support the REP escape sequence which ncurses started to use around that time. VTE (GNOME Terminal) had already added support for it in Ubuntu 18.04, chances are that Konsole had not. I suspect that your comment with the htop breakage is valid for Konsole but not for GNOME Terminal.

Comment: @egmont can't speak for the original problem, but I get the same result with WSL's terminal (whatever that is).

Comment: Setting `TERM` in `.bashrc` is a wrong thing to do. See http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/TERM.html#MIS-CONFIGURATION

Comment: “xterm-256color” does not exists in my `/use/share/terminfo/x`n, which causes me some troubles, so it is not always a good value.

Comment: @Arusekk that link or site seems broken - I can't get jdebp.eu to resolve (tried other jdebp.eu links found through Google, same result.

Comment: @lessthanideal https://web.archive.org/web/20201109162759/http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/TERM.html#MIS-CONFIGURATION archived on 2020-01-10, retrieved 2021-06-21

Comment: @Arusekk that works for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, in **init/main.c** this environment is defined:

```
static const char *argv_init[MAX_INIT_ARGS+2] = { "init", NULL, };
const char *envp_init[MAX_INIT_ENVS+2] = { "HOME=/", "TERM=linux", NULL, };
```

and then called with **do-execve()**:

```
static int run_init_process(const char *init_filename)
{
    argv_init[0] = init_filename;
    pr_info("Run %s as init process\n", init_filename);
    return do_execve(getname_kernel(init_filename),
        (const char __user *const __user *)argv_init,
        (const char __user *const __user *)envp_init);
}
```

This **pr_info()** appears as:

```
]# dmesg |grep 'Run'
[    1.291323] Run /init as init process
```

So the default is "TERM=linux", right from the start.