# Why xterm displays 256 colors (not xterm-256color)?

Tags: gnome-terminal, xterm

Could someone explain this? I'm using `gnome-terminal`. First, some information:

```
# echo $TERM
xterm

# infocmp xterm
Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /lib/terminfo/x/xterm
colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64

# tput colors
8
```

I wrote simple script to create codes for extended set of colors:

```
# Output file (current directory) and text.
OFILE='xterm256_colors_test.sh'
OFILE_COLORS='terminal_256_colors'
OTEXT='Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem...'

# Clearing the contents from previous runs.
if [ -e $OFILE ] || [ -e $OFILE_COLORS ]
then
  > $OFILE
  > $OFILE_COLORS
fi

# Bang!
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n' | tee --append $OFILE $OFILE_COLORS &> /dev/null
echo -e "\necho -e \"" | tee --append $OFILE &> /dev/null

# \x1b is a control character changing behaviour of the shell.
# It is also the <Ctrl+V><Esc> sequence.
for i in {016..255}; do
  echo -e "\x1b[38;5;${i}m $OTEXT $i \x1b[0m" >> $OFILE
  echo -e "color${i}=\"\[\033[38;5;${i}m\]\"" >> $OFILE_COLORS
done

# End of echo.
echo '"' | tee --append $OFILE &> /dev/null

# The file should be executable.
chmod +x $OFILE
```

Despite the basic `xterm` terminal emulator when I run the generated script I can see all 240 colors. Why? I thought I should change `$TERM` to `xterm-256color` first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `TERM` environment variable is a way that you, the user,
can tell programs (e.g., `emacs`, `grep`, `less`, `ls`, and `vim`)
what kind of terminal they are running on, so they will know its parameters, including what capabilities it has and what [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) they need to issue to access them.  This exists because it’s too hard, in general,
for the software to determine this for itself
(and was pretty much impossible when users interfaced
with computers through [terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) that were external,
and only connected to the computer by a data cable).

`gnome-terminal` is a program that provides terminal-like services
to the user and the programs that the user runs within the terminal. 
`gnome-terminal` may be aware of environment variables
that were set in *its* environment,
before it was invoked (`DISPLAY` being the obvious example),
but it has no knowledge of environment variables that are set
in in the processes that are running under it.

So, `gnome-terminal` has whatever capabilities it has. 
It may be possible to adjust/constrain these externally,
e.g., through command-line options, the pre-existing environment,
configuration files, and dialogs in the window frame,
but not by changing `TERM` in the shell in the window. 
If it’s capable of displaying 256 colors,
then it’s capable of displaying 256 colors,
and you will be able to cause it to do so
by sending it the appropriate escape sequences. 
But, as long as you have `TERM` set to `xterm`,
the programs that you run will believe that you are telling them
that they are running in an eight-color-capable terminal,
*and so they will restrict their requests (escape sequences)
to those capabilities*. 
You need to set `TERM` to `xterm-256color`,
not to enable `gnome-terminal` to display 256 colors,
but to tell programs like `grep` and `ls` to *ask* it
to use more than 8 colors.

Comment: Vaguely related: [Where does the TERM environment variable default get set?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198794/80216)