# How can I make Debian 8's terminal show box-drawing characters?

Tags: prompt, unicode

I just upgraded to Debian 8 with a fresh install and my terminal prompt (`prompt adam2 8bit` with ZSH) no longer displays some characters correctly:
[image: Missing unicode characters]

I've checked the terminal encoding (set to Unicode UTF-8) and the `$TERM` environment variable (xterm-256color) as well as multiple terminal emulators and fonts, but nothing seems to give me actual unicode characters. Moreover, this happens with a completely bare `.zshrc` after having issued

```
    $ autoload -Uz promptinit
    $ promptinit
    $ prompt adam2 8bit
```

to the terminal. My `locale` reads

```
    LANG=en_US.utf8
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
    LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
    LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
    LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Post enough of your configuration (`.zshrc` and any other relevant file) to reproduce the problem — basically we need to see your prompt setting. Also tell us the output of `locale`.

Comment: BTW, `$TERM` has no effect on what the terminal emulator can do — see [Why xterm displays 256 colors (not xterm-256color)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205270/80216)

Comment: Does it depend on the font you use in the terminal emulator?

Comment: @jofel Not as far as I can tell. All of the fonts I've checked do the same thing (and the font I'm using, DejaVu mono, worked previously).

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a problem with your `$PS1` variable. The `$PS1` variable is defined in your `zshrc` file. This file is located in `/etc/zshrc`
The `$PS1` variable stores the encoded (ASCII I believe) information to produce your prompt. 
 The first thing you want to do is see what your `$PS1` is currently. To do this type `echo $PS1` in your terminal. The standard prompt for Debian 8 *ZSH* is `%m%#`, which equates to `hostname%` or whatever your hostname happens to be(my prompt is `localhost%`). Most likely, the reason for your odd terminal prompt is a messed up `$PS1` variable, so to change it back to the default Debian 8 ZSH prompt type `PS1="%m%#"` in your terminal... keep in mind that this is temporary and your prompt will be reset every time you exit the terminal. To make this change permanent open your `/etc/zshrc` file and append 
`PS1="%m%#"`
to the file. Type `exit` to close the terminal, and then open it up again. The new, fixed terminal prompt should be displayed.

#### On a side note

These instructions are for **ZSH**, *not* **bash**! The default prompt for bash in Debian 8 is `\u@\H: \w $` which equates to `username@hostname: ~ $` (If I was in the `/bin` directory, my prompt would look like `bradleysadowsky@localhost: /bin $`). The characters in a ZSH prompt are very different from the characters in the bash prompt. Bash has characters ZSH does not and vice versa. Another key difference is (mostly) in bash, the special `$PS1` characters start with a backslash(`\`), whereas in ZSH (mostly), the special `$PS1` characters start with a percent symbol(`%`) For a good list of the more useful ZSH escape characters go to [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Zsh/Guide#Prompts) webpage. For a comprehensive guide to the `$PS1` variable in bash and some escape characters for bash, go to [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) webpage.

#### Finally

To set up your own prompt just put those escape characters together in a way you like, and edit your /etc/zshrc adding your prompt to it. A good prompt that is useful and beautiful for ZSH is `[%n@%m] %~>` which is equivalent to `[username@hostname] ~>`, so for me (if I was in `/bin`) `[bradleysadowsky@localhost] /bin>`.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is supposed to relate to the question. It appears to just be miscellaneous information about customising your prompt that doesn't have much to do with solving the OP's problem.

Comment: I actually don't "manually" set a `PS1` variable anywhere; ZSH comes with a `prompt` command to view/set/customize a number of defaults. `prompt adam2` works fine for me, but `prompt adam2 8bit` (with the box-drawing characters) gives the glyph-not-found question marks.

Comment: @ Connor Glosser: I believe the solution (I am not an expert at ZSH, although something like this has worked for me in the past) is to simply run `prompt adam2 8bit` and then `echo $PS1`... set that to your PS1 manually, (to identify if this is an error with ZSH or and error with the prompt command), and if it works, then great, if not, then try looking for errors within that particular set of escape characters... Hopefully this will fix it...