# how can i stop auto login console and getty in raspbian jessie

Tags: boot, raspbian

How can i stop auto serial port auto login console and getty in raspbian jessie os and why `/etc/inittab/` is empty ?

Where can i get this

```
#Spawn a getty on Raspberry Pi serial line T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

in raspbian jessie ?

thanks salwan

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/inittab` is empty because it is a thing of the past.  Do not concern yourself with it.  It is now an irrelevance for you with your operating system.

Serial-port `getty` is auto-started by systemd as a consequence of a `serial-getty@AMA0.service` service unit being auto-generated when your system is configured with `ttyAMA0` as the console.  The *existence* of the service unit is controlled by where you have configured your console device to be, with boot-loader options, and the generator automatically `enable`s it.  Everything else is done in the usual systemd way as for any other service:

- Manually start and stop the service with:

  - ```
    systemctl start serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
    ```
  - ```
    systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
    ```
- Set the service to run automatically at bootstrap, or not, with:

  - ```
    systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
    ```
  - ```
    systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
    ```
- Mask out the automatic `enable` done by the generator:

  - ```
    systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
    ```

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/621209/43344
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198949/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233855/5132