# agetty : not a tty in auth.log file

Tags: debian, logs, tty, authentication

I was checking my `auth.log` file when I saw multiple lines like this one : `Jul 30 22:34:08 <server-name> agetty[31666]: /dev/ttyS1: not a tty`

Those lines are logged 4 times every 10 seconds, and it just doesn't stop.

I have a server running with Linux Debian9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause on Debian 9 is that you have a `console=ttyS1` setting on your kernel command line, which `systemd-getty-generator` is picking up, causing it to instantiate a `serial-getty@ttyS1` service.  This service runs Weitse Venema's `agetty` against the `ttyS1` device.  But you do not actually have a `/dev/ttyS1` terminal character device on your server.  The file (apparently) exists, but it is not a terminal character device file.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248313/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316279/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
systemctl stop getty@ttyS1
systemctl disable getty@ttyS1
```